# If $\sin{\theta}=2\cos{\theta}$ then what is $\cos^2{\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

this question is giving me some issue because i know sin and cos is the same as $45$ degrees but there is a $2$ on the right side where cosine is.

So how would i get $\theta$?

Comment: Try squaring both sides and remember the relationship between $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square both sides to get

$\begin{array}{l}
{\sin ^2}\theta  = 4{\cos ^2}\theta  \Rightarrow 1 - {\cos ^2}\theta  = 4{\cos ^2}\theta  \Rightarrow \\
{\cos ^2}\theta  = \frac{1}{5}
\end{array}$

Comment: oh, how simple.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$; note that $\cos^{2}\theta = 1 - \sin^{2}\theta$. Then by assumption $\cos^{2}\theta = 1 - 4\cos^{2}\theta$, so $\cos^{2}\theta = 1/5$.